# What are all the win conditions?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I was recently attacked and my attacker only used 14 archers, doing only 8% damage to my town, however, it is listed as a defeat. My town hall was destroyed, does losing your town hall count as a defeat?

Comment: I did this starting out, being that the town hall is annoyingly large. Makes it harder to get something set up for it.

Answer (score 8):

If your Town Hall is destroyed you are automatically defeated.

Current win coditions are:

-50% destruction

-Town Hall Destroyed

To get 3 stars you also have to reach 100% destruction.

A typical farming strategy is to leave your town hall exposed then watch the attacker gather up resources till you can attack for a revenge gaining mass amounts of resources.